# Send and parse the JSON to spring controller?

Tags: java, json, spring, jquery, spring-mvc

Suppose , If I have the `JSON` data like ,

```
var json = {"name":"kite Player","age":"25","hobby":"footbal"}
```

I can Send the `JSON` data by

```
var jsonData = JSON.Stringfy(json);
```

In `JQueryAjax` ,

```
data = jsonData ,
```

I can parse the JSON data in the spring controller by,

```
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "personDetails.html")
    public @ResponseBody Result math(@RequestBody final Persons persons) {

         String name = person.getName();
         String age = persons.getAge();
         String hobby = persons.getHobby();
         // Other process
    }
}
```

How can I parse the `JSON` in the `Spring controller`, If I need to send multiple person details in `JSON` like ,

```
var json = [ {"name":"kite Player","age":"25","hobby":"footbal"},  
             {"name":"Steve","age":"40","hobby":"fishing"},
             {"name":"Marker","age":"28","hobby":"cricket"}
           ]
```

Hope our stack members will give a good solution.

Comment: Use a parsing library like GSON ! The second case is an array , any JSON parser will be able to handle it.

Comment: I need to use the jakson

Comment: please check this http://java2practice.wordpress.com/2013/03/14/how-to-pass-json-object-string-or-jsonarray-string-from-javascript-to-spring-controller/

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "personDetails.html")
public @ResponseBody Result math(@RequestBody List<Persons> personList) { ... }
```

--EDITED AND ADDED EXAMPLE--

I've tested this locally and it works for me. Here's code snippet:

```
public class TestController {
    public static class Test {                                                    
        String name;                                                                 

        public String getName() {                                                    
            return name;                                                                
        }                                                                            

        public void setName(String name) {                                           
            this.name = name;                                                           
        }                                                                            
    }                                                                             


    @RequestMapping(value = "/debug/test1.json", method = RequestMethod.POST)     
    @ResponseBody                                                                 
    public Test[] testList1(@RequestBody Test[] test) {                           
        return test;                                                                 
    }                                                                             

    @RequestMapping(value = "/debug/test2.json", method = RequestMethod.POST)     
    @ResponseBody                                                                 
    public List<Test> testList2(@RequestBody List<Test> test) {                   
        return test;                                                                 
    }                                                                     
}
```

Here are the test results (I tested it with curl):

```
    Request:
    curl --header "Content-type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json"  --data '[{"name": "John"}, {"name": "Jack"}]' http://localhost:8080/app/debug/test1.json
    Response:
    [{"name":"John"},{"name":"Jack"}]

    Request:
    curl --header "Content-type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json"  --data '[{"name": "John"}, {"name": "Jack"}]' http://localhost:8080/app/debug/test2.json
    Response:
    [{"name":"John"},{"name":"Jack"}]
```

PS. Somethime it's hard to get any debug information in spring MVC when JSON request fails before it reaches controller. To get the debug info, in some cases you need to set debug level of spring MVC to trace. I usually add this to my log4j.properties when I need to verify why a JSON request failed:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation=TRACE
```

Comment: The request doesn't enter into the controller when I used the **@RequestBody**

Comment: I edited my answer to provide an example. Do you receive any exceptions in the log when your request fails?

Comment: I suggest copy-pasting example to your project, and testing it out with curl as was specified. Places where things can go wrong are not sending Content-type and Accept headers from jQuery, incorrect json, etc. If you could post the code you tried with and which doesn't work and also contents (with headers) from the request made with jQuery perhaps I could help further.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the each member details in a JsonObject within a Json Array and then you can iterate through the array and get the individual JSON objects. You can see the documentation of JSON for all the available methods to get and set the data.

Also I would suggest you to use GSON (google -json) they are Memory friendly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "personDetails.html")
public @ResponseBody Result math(@RequestBody List< Persons > persons) {
    for (Persons person : persons) {
        String name = person.getName();
        String age = person.getAge();
        String hobby = person.getHobby();
        // Process the data
    }
}
```