# Returning ModelAndView in ajax spring mvc

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring

Hi am using spring mvc + ajax. I made a ajax call by passing a userid. And everything goes fine successfully returned to ajax but when i alert the response its simple showing the html page code. Please help me to sort out this prob.
I think i didnt coded my ajax well.Help me to in correct way

Controller code:

```
  public @ResponseBody ModelAndView abc(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
        HttpSession session, ModelMap map){

      ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("abcd.page",
                "commandName", object);
           return modelAndView;
```

Ajax code :

```
     $(".userDetails").click(function() {
            alert("clicked");
        var userId=$(this).parent().parent(). parent().find(".userId"). 
                       text().trim();
            alert("userId :"+userId);
            $.ajax({

            url : 'ABC.htm',
            type : 'GET',
            data: {userId:userId},
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {  
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");  
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");  
            },  
            success : function(response) {
                alert("success");
                alert(response);
            },
            error : function(res) {
                alert("error");
            },

        });

            return false;
        });
```

The output for the alert(response); is
[image]

**EDIT:** Can any one please tell why ajax giving html content on success... After many changes i made getting the same alert.

**Edited Again :** I think i dont have any problem in controller. Please suggest me solution to code my ajax correctly. It seems error here. How to get a ModelAndView object in ajax

Comment: add dataType: 'json'  Also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673656/how-to-use-ajax-jquery-in-spring-web-mvc/1683289#1683289

Comment: Thanks for ur immediate reply. Even that also not working suresh

Comment: Hitham i did as you suggest. Its giving alert("error");

Comment: No suresh again its alerting the same. Can you please tell me at which scenario ajax will give html page content in success.. Hope this will help me to find the solution

Comment: Check this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613927/send-and-parse-the-json-to-spring-controller/17618790#17618790

Comment: @MonickaAkilan what is version of spring are you using?

Answer (score 11):

You don't get a `ModelAndView` object in AJAX. Spring uses `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` instances to handle your handler method's return value. For `ModelAndView`, it uses `ModelAndViewResolverMethodReturnValueHandler`. For `@ResponseBody`, it uses `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor`. These are checked in a specific order and the one for `ModelAndView` has higher priority. Therefore, when you return a `ModelAndView`, Spring will add the model attributes to the full `Model` and then resolve your view name to, probably, a `jsp` and write the response from that `jsp`, giving you some HTML. Since AJAX just sees the response from the request, it will see HTML.

If you want to return JSON, don't return a `ModelAndView`, return the model object directly or write JSON directly to the response yourself.