# Pass model object from spring controller to jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to pass a model object from spring controller to jsp. But the object is not rendering on the target page.

**Controller**

```
    @Path("test");
    public ModelandView gettest(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
            ModelandView responseView = new ModelandView(new JsonView());
            //some code here
            if (somecondition) {
                responseView.setViewName("track/trackvehicle");
                responseView.addObject("JSONdata", vehicleID);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Not present");
            }
            return responseView;
        }
```

**trackvehicle.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <input type="text" id="test_id" value="${JSONdata}"/>
```

But the textbox is not rendered with any data. What is the problem?

Comment: Why are you using `new JsonView()`? Also are you using Jersey with Spring, or just Spring MVC? You seem to have mixed both

Comment: @geoand : Sir Its an ajax based application so I have used JsonView()
And its just Spring MVC

Comment: Thanks for the info! Why do you have the `@Path` annotation? That is not Spring MVC

Comment: @geoand:Sorry sir. Yes it is Requestmapping

Comment: `{$JSONdata}` should be `${JSONdata}`

Comment: @JBNizet : sir it was typing mistake here sorry. i have edited

Comment: OK. So all the code you provided is not the actual code which doesn't work? Post the actual code. A @Controller annotation on a method wouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
@Controller
public class YourController {    
    @RequestMapping("test")
    public ModelAndView gettest() {
        //some code here
        if (somecondition) {
            return new ModelAndView("track/trackvehicle", "JSONdata", vehicleID);
        }

        System.out.println("Not present");
        return new ModelAndView("track/trackvehicle");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir I did the same but still not getting required results on my jsp. I tried to retrieve the value using ${JSONdata}.

Comment: Is the controller method getting called? Is the JSP showing but without the correct data?

Comment: Sir controller is getting called. The console also says the model object is added to request in view with name track/trackvehicle. Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/jsp/track/trackvehicle.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'track/trackvehicle'

Comment: Could you please update your question with produced HTML of input with id `test_id`?

Comment: It would be helpful to the actual HTML that is sent to the browser by the server. Page Source in your browser should shot it

Comment: Sir thank u. I just tried to print request.getAttribute("JSONdata"); on my jsp where i want the results. Its printing the perfect answer on console. But the same if i do as <%=request.getAttribute%> it returns null.

Comment: in a scriplet <%System.out.println("DATA"+request.getAttribute("JSONdata"); %> 
This gave perfect output sir on the console.

Comment: Can you share your project so I can check it?

Comment: If you get the chance to upload it, let me know :)

Comment: ok sir thank you. will try uploading atleast the flow and snippets of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned in the comment section its ajax based in spring mvc...

how you are hitting this ajax url....

for ajax calls in spring mvc use @ResponseBody annotation and hit the url using ajax methods like classic ajax or jquery ajax or jquery get functions and load the value.

Hope this below links will give more clear picture for you

[Returning ModelAndView in ajax spring mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976297/returning-modelandview-in-ajax-spring-mvc)

[How to render a View using AJAX in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816080/how-to-render-a-view-using-ajax-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: Great links :) Thank u . But my ajax call is from one jsp and i want the response to other jsp. So i Use return new ModelAndView("track/trackvehicle", "JSONdata", vehicleID);
This is rendering the model object to the trackvehicle.jsp page but using jstl tag me not able to retrieve values.

Comment: I think you are not clear with your requirment. AJAX is mostly used to load part of a page or little bit data or only data instead of the page. AJAX is called from client side means from the browser and will hit the server and will get the response back to client wherever it called. Based on your comment I think you may looking for page redirection.